# how to check if coredata's array of type nsdata is empty for some index or not(image stored in coredata)

Tags: core-data, nsdata

i successfully saved the array of images as nsdata in coredata.
MY Question is - how can i check if there is an image exists at particular index(2) or not ??
Here is my code for retrieving data

var tableImageArray = NSData

func ShowCoreData(){

```
    // core data - show
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SavedIdea")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    do {
        var result:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if (result.count > 0) {
            self.tableTitleArray = result.valueForKey("heading") as! [String]
            print(tableTitleArray)
            self.tableDetailArray = result.valueForKey("detail") as! [String]
            self.tableTypeArray = result.valueForKey("type") as! [String]
            self.tableHoursArray = result.valueForKey("time") as! [String]
            self.tableImageArray = result.valueForKey("image") as! [NSData]

         //   print(" image array nsdata -- \(tableImageArray)")
        }else{
           // print("0 result appear....error")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }catch {
        let fetchError = ("returned error is \(error as! NSError)")
        print(fetchError)
    }

}
```

I got the whole array as NSdata in tableImageArray Then Suppose there is no image or value at index 2 but index 1,3 of tableImageArray  have values. This is giving me BAD_Exc error   at this line -
 if tableImageArray[indexPath.row].length > 0 whenever no image found

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as! OTPTableViewCell

        cell.LabelTitle.text = tableTitleArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.LabelDetail.text = tableDetailArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.LabelType.text = tableTypeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.LabelHours.text = String(tableHoursArray[indexPath.row])
      //  print(tableImageArray[indexPath.row])
        if tableImageArray[indexPath.row].length > 0   {
           cell.ImgView.image =  UIImage(data: tableImageArray[indexPath.row])//(named: tableImageArray[indexPath.row])

        }else{
            cell.imageWidthConstraints.constant = 0
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: What about testing `if let imageData = tableImageArray[indexPath.row]`, or that kind of stuff? Also, I wouldn't recommend to use multiples arrays (it's not easy to maintain them synchronized. Instead, use a custom class that represent your object (or dict), and use a single array.

Comment: not its not working...... i just want to know how to check if that index has any value or not . if not then how to check......if tableImageArray[indexPath.row].length > 0